# How can I parse the Output from MongoDB in Python

Tags: python, pymongo

I was recently working on my Discord bot. I came up with a new feature. It requires me to store Guild IDs and Channel IDs and retrieve them Frequently. Tho I inserted the data into the Database but I do not know how I can parse this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert the cursor into JSON format. What are you using to post and retrieve data? One method would be to use PyMongo.

In your console, use Pip to install Pymongo:

```
pip install pymongo
```

Now you can easily convert to JSON:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps
json_data = dumps(yourmongodata)
```

Comment: But how do I extract the Data from the given dump? I tried several meathods but Nothing works